# Validator that checks for null field

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a field in a django model where null=True and blank=True, but the user has to enter content in the field. Essentially, I need a page load to take place after the user clicks "Submit" (i.e. I don't want django's built in field validator to just pop up if a required field is left null). I want to accomplish this with a validator in the models.py file that checks to see if the field has been populated.

```
def validate7(value):
    if bool(value) == False:
        raise ValidationError(_('Please fill in the field below.'))
    else:
        pass


class CarProfile (models.Model):                                     
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate7])
```

Unfortunately, the user can submit the form while these field is left blank.

Within the validator, I've also tried:

```
    if value == None:
        raise ValidationError(_('Please fill in the field below.'))
```

and

```
    if value == '':
        raise ValidationError(_('Please fill in the field below.'))
```

and

```
    if not value:
        raise ValidationError(_('Please fill in the field below.'))
```

Nothing seems to work. I've implemented other validators on my site, but I just can't seem to crack this one. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `print()` the value in the console when user submit, just to see the actual value, what it looks, its type.... **DEBUG trick**

Answer (score 0):

Custom validators don't resolve on fields that are left null. Use novalidate on your form tag to prevent the html5 popups from being displayed.